# Convergence of the moments of a square-integrable martingale with respect to time

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

I'm reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3945806/1019043) question, i.e.,

> 1. I have a $M$ continuous martingale, how can I show that if $t_n \underset{n}{\rightarrow}t$ then:
>    $$
>    M_{t_n}\overset{L^1}{\underset{n}{\rightarrow}}M_t
>    $$
>    assuming that $\mathbb{E}\left[\underset{t\in[0,T]}{\sup}|M_t|\right]<+\infty$.
> 2. Given that $M$ is square integrable how to show that
>    $t \mapsto \mathbb{E}\left[M_t^2\right]$ is continuous.

and its [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3945855/1019043), i.e.,

> 1. $M_t$ is continuous, $M_{t_n}(\omega) \to M(t)(\omega)$, hence we have almost sure convergence.
>
> Further, $|M_{t_n}| \le \sup_{t \in [0,1]} M_t = \eta$.  As $\mathbb{E} \eta < \infty$ we have $M_{t_n} \to  M_t$ in $L_1$ by dominated convergence theorem.
>
> 2. In general case it's not true - so I think you meant that $M$ is countinious in the second problem also.
>
> As in previous case, it's sufficient to prove that $\sup_{t \in [0,1]} M_{t}^2$ is in $L_1$. It follows from Jensen's inequality for conditional expectations. Indeed, we have
> $\mathbb{E} (M_T | \mathcal{F}_t) = M_t$. Hence
>
> $$\color{blue}{\eta =  \mathbb{E} ( M_T^2 | \mathcal{F}_t)} \ge \Bigl(\mathbb{E} ( M_T | \mathcal{F}_t) \Bigr)^2 = M_t^2 \Longrightarrow \sup_{t \in [0,T]} M_{t}^2 \le \eta$$
> and
> $\mathbb{E} \eta = \mathbb{E} M_T^2< \infty$, because our martingale is in $L_2$.

---

Could you explain how $\eta$ in part (2.) of the answer is defined?

If $\eta :=  \mathbb{E} ( M_T^2 | \mathcal{F}_t)$ then $\eta$ certainly depends on $\mathcal F_t$ and thus on $t$. However, the proof would not work with my interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that part of my proof didn't work. Here's a new one.

$X_t$ is martingale and hence $X_t^2$ is submartingale and $X_t^2 \ge 0$. Hence by Doob's maximal inequality  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality or
https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/lecture-11-doobs-martingale-maximal-inequalities/) we get

$$\mathbf{E}\left[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T} |X_s|^p\right] \leq \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^p\mathbf{E}[|X_T|^p]$$ and if $p=2$ we have
$\mathbf{E}\left[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T} |X_s|^2\right] < \infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated support!

Comment: @Analyst You are welcome!

Comment: I have a problem understanding the proof in the notes by Fabrice Baudoin. If you don't  mind, please have a look at my recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633962/how-the-author-uses-mct-to-complete-his-proof-of-doob-s-martingale-maximal-inequ).